# ViewScoped is working like ApplicationScoped

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi all please before mark my question as duplicated I want to tell you that I made a huge research including those questions

[Unexpected survival of a @ViewScoped bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205348/unexpected-survival-of-a-viewscoped-bean)

[ViewScope not destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009062/viewscope-not-destroy)

[ViewScope beans behaves like it has application scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432006/viewscope-beans-behaves-like-it-has-application-scope)

But I´m asking because  I´m using a diferent version of the tools and  don´t found any possible solution to my problem.

This is the situation

I´m using primefaces 5.1 Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, Spring security 3.1.1.RELEASE,JSF 2.2.8 and Apache 8 .

I enter to my app and start to work, but if other person in other machine with different browser and different session id enter to the same xhtml view, he will see the data that I wrote. So looks like all the controllers of my aplication are in @ApplicationScoped but all of them are @ViewScoped

In the investigation process I did a debug and in the first acces to a view, that view call the controller, but when other person acces to the same view the controller is not called, I don´t know  how the view gets the data  if  doesn´t call the controller.

This is one of my controllers

```
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
@Controller
public class CreateRepoController {

    @Autowired
    private IRepoFacade repositorioFacade;
    @Autowired
    private ISecureFacade secureFacade; 
    //Methods


}
```

Note I also tried with `import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;` instead the javax viewScoped

the view is called from a menu

```
            <p:submenu label="Repo">
                        <p:menuitem value="Create" url="/secured/createRepo.xhtml" />
            </p:submenu>
```

All the application have the same behavior is not just one view

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

Answer (score 0):

You have posted very few details. So I'll give you some hints on how to troubleshoot.

1. test your beans with session scope instead of view scope and check if you get a different behavior. view scope is sometimes tricky and may not work as expected. if you get a different request per user then investigate what do you have in your bean that is trigering the wrong behavior when switched to view scope.
2. avoid mixing CDI annotations with JSF annotations. I've had interoperativity problems when merging them.
3. Omnifaces ViewScope is a CDI annotation for JSF 2.0/2.1. In JSF 2.2 there is a standard annotation for CDI as part of Java EE 7 in javax.faces.view package.
4. try switching to all CDI if ypu still have problems. Instead of @ManagedBean use @Named and @ViewScoped from javax.faces.view.

Answer (score 0):

Try do remove `@Controller` annotation and extend `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` to enable the injections.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CreateRepoController extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements Serializable {
     @Autowired
     private IRepoFacade repositorioFacade;
     @Autowired
     private ISecureFacade secureFacade; 
     //Methods
}
```

It works with with Spring 4.0.6 and PF 5.1.